Local Images are not visible in react native android application , in android 14
After updating to sdk 34 when I'm running my application on Android 14, local images are not visible whereas its working fine in Android 13.
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0" minSdkVersion = 23 compileSdkVersion = 34 targetSdkVersion = 34
(and its using Gradle 8.0.1, java 11.0)
I tried url instead of require, but it didnt work
